# Understand firing angle chart in dual converter

Tags: converter, ac-dc

How to understand below [Firing Angle Chart](https://circuitdigest.com/tutorial/dual-converter-working-types-and-modes),
[image: Dual-Converter-Firing-Angle-Graph]

I guess the y axis should be voltage of the source, but what is the x axis, why a1/a2 points right, the location of 0⁰/90⁰/180⁰ seems quite strange.

Hints are:

- ⍺1 + ⍺2 = 180⁰
- In rectifier mode(Rect.), 0⁰< ⍺1/⍺2 < 90⁰,
- In inverter mode(inv.), 90⁰< ⍺1/⍺2 < 180⁰,